# Существование меток [поиск-библиотек], [поиск-программ] и т.п

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Вообще, интересная ситуация. У нас есть метки [поиск-библиотек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba), [поиск-программ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc) и т.п.

Но я очень часто вижу, как вопросы по поиску библиотек, плагинов и т.п. закрываются "по причине того, что необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ". Например, [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/710768/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c) вопрос.

Так, всё же, закрывать такие вопросы или нет?

Comment: `[поиск-библиотек]` была создана 13 дней назад. Странно что никто не заметил и не удалил.... 
`[поиск-программ]`  - 8 месяцев и тоже странно что никто не заметил

Comment: [tag:поиск-программ] создан @Qwertiy =)

Comment: ааа... там поиск-программ @Qwertiy навешивал...ну тогда понятно %)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я заметил, но забил болт. Все равно их налепят снова, толку нет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я её и подчищаю иногда, когда невпопад ставят :)

Comment: @vp_arth, а как ты узнал, кто создал метку?

Comment: @Qwertiy https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/630499/revisions  "создано 20 фев в 17:30 Qwertiy♦"

Comment: @Suvitruf, это создание описания, а не метки. Впрочем, если не ошибаюсь, в данном случае я это сделал одновременно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, метка была создана в 17:08  того же дня)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [поиск-программ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc)

Я создал эту метку. Она предназначена для отделения вопросов, связанных с поиском решения специфических задач без программирования. Например, в администрировании или несколько более широких задачах.

У метки есть краткое и полное описание с указанием того, как должен выглядеть хороший вопорс. Аналогичный англоязычный сайт: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

> [поиск-библиотек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba)

А вот про такую метку у меня когда-то была мысль. Но в итоге я пришёл к выводу, что эта метка слишком спорная. Поиск программ говорит о необходимости выполнить задачу с помощью некой готовой программы без программирования, если расширить эту аналогию на поиск библиотек, то получается, что нужна библиотека для конкретной задачи. Но тут возникает нюанс с тем, что библиотеки всё равно надо как-то использовать - они не являются автономными единицами и лучше спросить просто как выполнить задачу, а в тексте написать о библиотеке.

В общем, не знаю, нужна ли эта метка.

Comment: Поиск программ — это не то же самое, что решение проблем в области администрирования.

Comment: @Arhad, я и не говорил, что это то же самое. Там же написано "например". Если бы это было то же самое, была бы нужна только одна из этих меток.

Comment: стоит отделить [tag:поиск-программ] метку (аналог softwarerecs.SE) -- могут быть полезные вопросы (хотя нужно посмотреть что на практике происходит). Метка [tag:поиск-библиотек] не выглядит полезной -- это ведёт либо слишком широким вопросам, либо субъективным (кому что нравится без объективный предпочтений, так как задача не слишком конкретно поставлена). Стоит предпочитать «Как сделать конкретную вещь X» вместо «какую библиотеку использовать в области Y» Если Y достаточно узко определён, тогда вопрос можно переформулировать в howto вариант вместо закрытия.