# Ещё раз про вопросы о поиске библиотек/плагинов/инструментов/приложений

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, тематика

По мотивам старого обсуждения: [Что делать с вопросами про поиск библиотек/плагинов/инструментов/приложений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2615/15479).

И на фоне подобных вопросов: [Есть ли готовые библиотеки календаря для telegram bot реализованные на php?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1013769/15479).

Прошло больше 3-х лет. Возможно, мнение на этот счёт поменялось у сообщества. Предлагаю обсудить по новой.

**За:**

- Вопросы в целом [вписываются в тематику](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

  > к инструментам для разработки: языкам программирования, средам, операционным системам, пакетам программ, фреймворкам, библиотекам

**Против:**

- [Ответы-ссылки не приветствуются](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).
- Ссылки на библиотеки и т.п. могут протухнуть.
- Без пояснения не особо полезен.
- Часто opinion based, по правилам должны быть закрыты.

Предлагаю обсудить:

1. Закрывать ли такие вопросы?
2. Если оставлять, то нужно ли требовать приводить в ответе пример использования библиотеки, а иначе переносить в комментарии?

Comment: Также призываю использовать метки [поиск-библиотек] [поиск-api] [поиск-программ] и т.д.

Comment: @Kromster можете в ответе про это написать )

Comment: @Kromster А вот автор этих меток [уже сомневался](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6367/213987) в их необходимости. Я позвал его в эту тему обсудить текущее видение.

Comment: @AK, у этих меток разные авторы. Я автор только одной из них и в её необходимости я не сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 13):

TL;DR:

> Закрывать ли такие вопросы?

Нет

> Если оставлять, то нужно ли требовать приводить в ответе пример использования библиотеки, а иначе переносить в комментарии?

Требовать, иначе переносить в комментарии.

N.B. На правах личного мнения.

[Фраза из справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию" трактуется исключительно в духе "подскажите ссылку на скачивание". Такого рода вопросы нежелательны. Если ты знаешь, какую библиотеку ты ищещь -- то стоит искать линки на скачивание в гугле, на официальных сайтах.

Вопросы же вида "какой готовой библиотекой можно воспользоваться чтобы решить такую-то задачу" являются вполне нормальными вопросами и не могут закрываться с описанной выше причиной "поиск библиотек запрещён".

Дело в том, что множество типовых задач уже давно кем-то решены и если вы не бьётесь в каких-то узких областях или решаете задачи на bleeding edge где активно идёт обсуждение с Джоном Скитом -- то вполне вероятно, что ваша задача уже вполне имеет готовую библиотеку, порой и не одну.

По части требования примера. Считаю, что наличие какого-то наглядного и простого примера является обязательным для ответов, иначе ответ мало помогает будущим читателям вопроса. Даже если автору вопроса уже всё понятно или сразу понятно -- уровень читающих вопросы разный.

Answer (score 10):

Вообще-то не вижу причин считать, что что-то изменилось.

- Вопрос про библиотеки должен быть достаточно конкретен, чтобы на него можно было дать конкретный ответ.
- Название библиотеки само по себе является ответом.
- Желательно (но не обязательно) в ответе перечислить преимущества и недостатки и пояснить, почему рекомендуется использовать именно её.
- Можно привести пример кода, если он требуется.

Отличие библиотеки от простой ссылки в том, что её всегда можно найти, даже если официальный сайт исчезнет. Для этого нужно именно название библиотеки.