# Почему такой ответ, который не ответ, считается за ответ?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, тревоги

[Вот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1086085/282277), который я пометил тревогой как "не является ответом". Однако модератор со мной не согласился.

Хотелось бы понять, почему. Ответа на вопрос там нет, две трети текста вообще не по делу. Чистый комментарий.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тревогу отклонил я.

Ответ является вполне нормальным ответом, если он натолкнул автора на правильный путь. В данном случае, совет про MAVlink был принят автором.

В таком виде в целом подпадает под пункт "Поиск библиотек/инструментов", который у нас, в общем-то, является онтопиком:

- [Что делать с вопросами про поиск библиотек/плагинов/инструментов/приложений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2615/15479).
- [Ещё раз про вопросы о поиске библиотек/плагинов/инструментов/приложений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9491/15479).

Согласен, что такие односложные ответы могут выглядеть лишь как комментарий. Решение о том, переносить ли в комментарии, принимает в итоге модератор (если была тревога). Другой модератор может быть и перенёс бы. Для меня в подобных случаях большой вес имеет факт того, что автор вопроса принял ответ.