# За что у меня отняли возможность ставить тревоги?

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги, блокировка

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нашел [скрипт](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/139623/marginal-short-answers-with-links), который находит плохие ответы (ссылки и т.д.) и стал их методично тревогать. По-моему ничего вредного для сообщества в этом нет, даже наоборот. За что у меня отняли возможность ставить тревоги?

**P.S.** Да, кстати, переводик выкатите ("You may raise flags again").

Comment: @Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik Доставился тревог ;)

Comment: Многие тревоги на сообщениях были отклонены, т.к. подобные сообщения в рамках правил. Это, по большей части, касается ваших тревогах на сообщениях в вопросах на поиск библиотек/плагинов и т.п.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Эх...

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Н-да, надо было сегодня продолжат удалять "спасибо".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Многие тревоги на сообщениях были отклонены, т.к. подобные сообщения в рамках правил. Это, по большей части, касается ваших тревог на сообщениях в вопросах на поиск библиотек/плагинов и т.п.

Запрет на новые тревоги выдала автоматика. Модераторы сами такое сделать не могут)

Плюс, это, скорее, просьба, не нужно проявлять излишнее рвении в очень старых сообщениях.

Comment: Хм, сказали на 7 дней, а сегодня уже разрешили ;) Это хорошо.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica не рекомендую использовать автоматизированные средства. Цель тревог - помочь сообществу, а не набить число тревог.

Comment: Да я понял. Это я зря. Просто сгоряча...

Comment: Удалил некоторое кол-во "спасибо" и думаю: какая от этого польза?  Просто накрутка. Тогда я поискал и думаю: "Ответ ссылка — не ответ. Он нарушает правила, значит его можно флагать". И стал их флагать. Я не знал, что они иногда допустимы.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica вот [одно из последних обсуждений по теме](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9491/15479).

Comment: Думаю надо обсудить это еще раз. Может сейчас мнение поменялось...

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10387/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba