# Ответы-ссылки в вопросах по поиску библиотек

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, ответы, тематика, ссылки

Вроде бы уже договорились, что такие вопросы закрывать не надо. Но как быть с ответами на них? Например, ответы ссылки неприемлемы, но тем не менее пока на такие вопросы часто отвечали ссылками.

Каким критериям по вашему мнению должен удовлетворять ответ на поиск-библиотек?

Comment: Прошлое обсуждение по теме: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9491/15479.

Comment: Ну вроде бы название библиотеки уже само по себе является ответом, а наличие или отсутствие ссылки уже не так важно, главное что по названию можно нагуглить и скачать. (Насчёт требования примера кода чёткого мнения не имею)

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Вроде все обсудили, так что надо задубликатить.

Answer (score 7):

Вроде про всё договорились:

## Сами вопросы:

- Не закрывать
  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9492/178988 (+14 -0)

## Ответы на них:

- Ссылка плюс название - минимально достаточный ответ
  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1639/178988 (+11 -5)

Answer (score 3):

Этот момент подробно не проговаривался тогда, оба ответа практически одинаково заплюсованы, но немного различаются в деталях.

У меня складывается следующее понимание:

1. Вопросы не закрываем с формулировкой "поиск библиотек" (если на него можно дать конкретный ответ - оставляем открытым)
2. Ответ является минимально достаточным если содержит название библиотеки + ссылку. При наличии этого уже не стоит ставить тревогу "не является ответом" и сносить в комментарии.
3. Желательно (но не обязательно) в ответе привести код с примером использования библиотеки, а также перечислить преимущества и недостатки по сравнению с другими.